# Update multiple records with different ids

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an app where a user can send a payment request to another user. When a request is created I save it this way

```
 public function createUserMoneyRequest(Request $request)
    {
    
    $recipient = User::where('phone_number', $request->phone_number)->first();
    $user = Auth::user();
 // money request sender
       $userRequestMoney = new UserMoneyRequest();
       $userRequestMoney->amount = $request->input('amount');
       $userRequestMoney->description = 'money request sent to '.$recipient->last_name.' '.$recipient->first_name.'';
       $userRequestMoney->status = 'pending';
       $userRequestMoney->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
       $userRequestMoney->save();
       
       
        

    // money request receiver
    $userRequestMoney = new UserMoneyRequest();
    $userRequestMoney->phone_number = $user->phone_number;
    $userRequestMoney->amount = $request->input('amount');
    $userRequestMoney->description ='money request from '.$user->last_name.' '.$user->first_name.'';
    $userRequestMoney->status = 'pending';
    $userRequestMoney->user_id = $recipient->id;
    $userRequestMoney->save();

    return  'request successful';
    }
```

so above the phone number belongs to the receiver which is used to save this data and show him in a notification.

Now when a request is paid or declined by the person the request is sent to... I want to update the `status` on both the sender and receiver to `paid` or `declined`

Right now I can pass the request Id on the side of the payer in a put request and update his record

```
  public function updateStatus(Request $request){
         
        $update = UserMoneyRequest::where('id', $request->reqId)->update([
            'status' => $request->setRequestStatus
        ]);
        return 'success';
      }
   

}
```

but can not figure out how to update on both side using the action of one side(payer).
How can I do this or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must create only one request with information of sender and receiver, it makes it easier to update and to make other operations on the data.

Comment: Thanks but I solved it by adding one more column to both information of sender and receiver that is identical and using it to set status of both records.